# Update table based on current record

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, cursor

In my PostgreSQL database I'm converting from integer keys to UUID for various reasons.  So right now I have table Person with an `ident serial primary key`, and table TeamPerson with a `person_id integer references Person (ident)`.

I then go and add a `uid UUID` column with a unique constraint to Person and a `person_uid references Person (uid)` column to TeamPerson.  So now I need to make all the person_uid correspond to the person_id references.  I'm wanting something like:

```
UPDATE TeamPerson
SET person_uid = (
    SELECT uid FROM Person WHERE ident = current_team_person_row.person_id
)
```

The `current_team_person_row` is my issue I'm trying to solve.  I think I need a cursor with a `WHERE CURRENT OF` but I'm just not grasping how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for: [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), known also as "dependent subquery"

> In a SQL database query, a correlated subquery (also known as a
>   synchronized subquery) is a subquery (a query nested inside another
>   query) that uses values from the outer query.

```
UPDATE TeamPerson tp
SET person_uid = (
    SELECT uid FROM Person p 
    WHERE p.ident = tp.person_id
)
```

Comment: Argh, I was so close!  Thanks!  :)